# Write data to empty json file

Tags: javascript, json, typescript

First I truncate the json file before first run.

For each run after that I want to keep appending to the json file. For first run since data is empty I get 'SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input'

```
    public jsondata = (newdata: string) => {

    var fs = require('fs');

    fs.readFile('output.json', function (err, data) {

       let json:any = [];
            console.log('some data =' + data + '=');

            if(data === '') {
            json = JSON.parse(newdata);
            json.push(newdata);
            }
            else {
            json = JSON.parse(data);
            json.push(newdata);
            }

        fs.writeFile('output.json', JSON.stringify(json, null, 4), (err) => {
            if (err) throw err;
            console.log('The json file has been saved');
        });
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
fs.readFile('output.json', 'utf-8', function (err, data) { 
    if (data === '') {
        json.push(newdata);
    }
```

Instead of

```
fs.readFile('output.json', function (err, data) {
    if(data === '') {
        json = JSON.parse(newdata);
        json.push(newdata);
    }
```

**WHY:**

If `output.json` is empty
From `fs.readFile('output.json', function (err, data) { ... })`,
`data` is `<Buffer >` instead of `''`(empty string)
So, with your code, `if (data === '')` always `false`
And
`json = JSON.parse(data)` generate `SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input`